# How can I sign message for a blockchain watch only bitcoin address

Tags: message-signing, watch-only, message-verification

I have to verify sign message for one of my blockchain bitcoin address. I couldn't find sign message or private key option in More Options beside all my bitcoin addresses. I thought maybe I have to import it.So I imported my own blockchain bitcoin address which I am mentioning below

1PSBpnjrzpHyKpyQuFaecdnA4WfDetdiwn

and it became a watch only address. In More Options I see only Archive, transfer and spent.
So what to do now ? Please help...

I do not have any bitcoins on this address, but I logged in using this bitcoin address as master address on a bitcoin gambling site and forgot the password.The only way I can recover my account is by verifying my bitcoin address

1PSBpnjrzpHyKpyQuFaecdnA4WfDetdiwn and pasting the signature to be provided by blockchain. I don't want to lose my BTC and LTC on this account.

So what to do now ? Please help...

Answer (score 2):

When you import an address as a 'watch only' address, it means exactly that: you can only 'watch' the address and see whatever funds are sitting in it. You cannot send transactions, or sign messages, with a watch only address.

This is because you just imported the address into your wallet, whereas if you imported the private key, then you would be able to sign the message (and send transactions, etc).

So you'll need to find some wallet software that can sign messages (and that you trust). Import the private key for that address, and then sign the message.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Can you suggest some bitcoin wallet software that will provide me with private key for my watch only address or sign message for my watch only address

Comment: @57bits If you don't have the private key, the address is not yours, and there is nothing we or you or anyone can do about it. As the name says, you are only watching the address. You must have imported it somewhere without access to the corresponding key. If you don't already have the key, that's the end of the story.

Comment: @57bits If you use the wallet that generated this address then the private keys should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can not sign a message with watch only address.

Signing requires private key.